# fix date multi formatted issue and reconstruct the date from different columns

Tags: python

I have table with mixed date formats some of these dates  (yyyy-mm-dd) others (dd-mm-yyyy) others (mm-dd-yyyy) others (dd/mm/yyy) and others with time andso on but i have 2 other columns (year) and (month) i need to write a code to extract the day from the multi formatted  date and save it in new column (Day_from _date) then reconstruct the date from the three columns in new column (New_date):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2023-01-02 00:00:00','01','2023'],
                   ['2023-01-02 00:00:00','01','2023'],
                   ['01/16/2023','01','2023'],
                   ['01/16/2023','01','2023'],
                   ['01/16/2023','01','2023'],
                   ['02/13/2023','02','2023'],
                   ['02/13/2023','02','2023'],
                   ['02/13/2023','02','2023'],
                   ['26/11/2018','11','2018'],
                   ['26/11/2018','11','2018'],
                   ['26/11/2018','11','2018'],
                   ['26/11/2018','11','2018'],
                   ['27/11/2018','11','2018'],
                   ['27/11/2018','11','2018'],

                  ],
                  columns=['Date','month','year'])
df
```

the expected result

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the below steps: 1- remove 00:00:00      (2) remove the the year in date column based on year column      (3) remove the month in date column based on month column        (4) remove all / and - then find the day ................ but unfortunately it does not worked with the date when the month = the day

Comment: maybe i need another way of thinking